# Set google maps marker icon properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to 'style' the markers from data from an xml using javascript:

```
        var title = 'Speed: '+$(this).find('Speed').text();
        var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
        var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();


        var markerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
        bounds.extend(markerCoords);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerCoords,
            title: title,
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                scale: 5,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#009933',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                rotation: 0,
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,2)
      },
```

So far this works great. I can't seem to do the same with the options within icon. The following is me trying to put the rotation number in the same way which doesn't display the marker at all:

```
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerCoords,
            title: title,
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                scale: 5,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#009933',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                rotation: $(this).find('rotation').text(),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,2)
      },
```

And neither does it when I try to add it as a variable before hand:

```
        var title = 'Speed: '+$(this).find('Speed').text();
        var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
        var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
        var rotation = $(this).find('rotation').text();

        var markerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
        bounds.extend(markerCoords);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerCoords,
            title: title,
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                scale: 5,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#009933',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                rotation: rotation,
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,2)
      },
```

The only thing I can think is that the whole icon needs to go in as one long string but I can't figure out how to get this done.

For clarity the data itself is coming from an xml file:

```
<markers>
 <marker>
  <lat>50.11966</lat>
  <lng>-5.54409</lng>
  <Speed>0</Speed>
  <rotation>0</rotation>
  <icon>google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE</icon>
  <fillColor>#0099FF</fillColor>
 </marker>
 <marker>
  <lat>50.12173</lat>
  <lng>-5.53225</lng>
  <Speed>200</Speed>
  <rotation>0</rotation>
  <icon>google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW</icon>
  <fillColor>#009933</fillColor>
 </marker>
</markers>
```

Can anyone help?

EDIT:

I am part of the way there thanks to Jared Smith. So the rotation works as that is a number, but the path and fillColor are both strings. Can someone advise how to do this with strings?

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerCoords,
            title: title,
            icon: {
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
                scale: 5,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#009933',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                rotation: parseInt($(this).find('rotation').text(), 10),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,2)
      },
```

EDIT 2:

This isn't rendering. Any ideas:

```
  var title = 'Speed: '+$(this).find('Speed').text();
        var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
        var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
        //var rotation = $(this).find('rotation').text();
        var type = (function(foo) {
            var arr = foo.find('icon').text().split('.');
            return arr[arr.length-1];
        })($(this))

        var markerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));
        bounds.extend(markerCoords);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: markerCoords,
            title: title,
            icon: {
                path: new google.maps.SymbolPath[arr],
                scale: 5,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#009933',
                fillOpacity: 1,
                rotation: parseInt($(this).find('rotation').text(), 10),
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0,2)
      },
```

And it doesn't when I use this either:

```
            icon: {
                path: new google.maps.SymbolPath[type],
```

Can you see if I am applying your code incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

From the [google maps API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Icon) the rotation property of the icon symbol object should be a number so `parseInt($(this).find('rotation').text(), 10);`

Per your comment below, you have another problem, the SymbolPath constructor needs to be called with `new`. As for how you're going to do that getting the value out of an XML file, you just need some code like this:

```
var type = (function(foo) {
    var arr = foo.find('icon').text().split('.');
    return arr[arr.length-1];
})($(this));
```

and then in the marker options

```
icon: {
    path: new google.maps.SymbolPath[type]()
```

If you can change the XML file then I recommend reducing the path line to just the SymbolPath value like `<icon>CIRCLE</icon>`

EDIT:
You need to make sure that you set the map for the marker objects. There are two ways of doing this:

1) Do it in the constructor options

```
var marker = new.google.maps.Marker({
    map: myGoogleMap,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
    title: 'my marker',
    icon: //blah, blah, blah
});
```

2) Do it with a method call in a loop after you've made them all:

```
for (var i=0, len=markers.length; i<len; ++i) {
    markers[i].setMap(myGoogleMap);
}
```

The second can also be used to hide markers, just `.setMap(null);` but either one will work fine (you don't need to do both).

Comment: Ahhh, this works. Do you know how I could make this work for "strings" for the strokeColor and path?

Comment: Updated my answer. striokeColor should work now as you've written it.

Comment: I feel like I am getting close but it still won't render. Any chance you could have a look at "Edit 2" above? Oh, and I changed the XML to show either FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW or CIRCLE.

Comment: Although you don't show it in your code, I'm assuming your setting the map property of the marker? `marker.setMap(myGoogleMapObject);`

Comment: i have:  markers.push(marker); at the end if that does it?

Comment: Nope. Your markers aren't rendering because you aren't telling them to. I'll update my answer.